# How to add Scroll Bar to GAS Modal Dialog Box?

Tags: scroll, google-apps-script, dialog, modal-dialog

I am wondering how I can add a scrollbar to my Google Apps Script code so I can scroll through my list of items in the dialog box.

The Sidebar method of my code (identical except for showModalDialog vs. showSidebar) DOES scroll, but the Dialog method does not.

I have tried adding overflow: auto; and overflow: scroll; to basically every div I can find, with no results (though iFrame within GAS should already be set to auto?).

The only info I can find relating to Apps Script, Dialog boxes, and scroll bars is app.createScrollPanel, which was deprecated last year.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function showSidebarAdd() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var addUi = HtmlService.createTemplate(getAddUi()).evaluate().getContent();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplate(addUi+
                                       "<script>\n" +
                                       "var data = "+
                                       getInvData()+
                                       "</script>")
                                       .evaluate()
                                       .setTitle('Add Items to Inventory')
                                       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Unsorted Inventory'));
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function showDialogAdd() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var addUi = HtmlService.createTemplate(getAddUi()).evaluate().getContent();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplate(addUi+
                                       "<script>\n" +
                                       "var data = "+
                                       getInvData()+
                                       "</script>")
                                       .evaluate()
                                       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                                       .setWidth(500)
                                       .setHeight(850)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Unsorted Inventory'));
    ui.showModalDialog(html,'Add Items to Inventory');
}
```

Here is what the scrollbar version looks like:
[Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WFFP.png)

Here is what the dialog version look like:
[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfuql.jpg)

Hopefully it can be done in a dialog box, because I much prefer the list to be in a pop out style with custom dimensions, rather than the squashed to the side sidebar

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code uses a function `getAddUi()` which is undefined.  We need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. There's a little bit of code to get the content to display though:

Comment: `function getAddUi(data) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('addUi');
  return html.evaluate().getContent();
}`

HTML file addUI code is quite long

Comment: Ok.  I'm just trying to figure out if this is an Apps Script question, or an HTML question.  It could be a little of both.  Can you reproduce the problem with a small amount of very basic HTML?  I copied and pasted your code into Apps Script to see if I could find the problem, but I'd need to create some HTML myself to test your code, and I don't know if the HTML that I create would help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem! By removing .setHeight() when creating the dialog box, the scrollbar presents itself and works properly.

Answer (score 0):

> "To resize a dialog that is already open, call google.script.host.setWidth(width) in client-side code."

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setWidth(Integer))